Search filenames NOT in an Excel list
I have this Excel list with approximately 200 names and I would like to perform a file explorer search of the files not containing any of the names in this list.
Any idea how to do this?
Thank you very much,

What research have you done and what have you tried? This will require a script, but this site is not a script-writing service. The discrete steps you will need to figure out are 1) read each line in the file, and 2) search your file system for the value read in step 1. What Windows version are you running?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
